# Jquery Browser Resize center Div even on scroll

Tags: jquery

I have this code...

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #567;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
  My center div...
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#container').css({
    position:'absolute',
    left: ($(window).width() - $('#container').outerWidth())/2,
    top: ($(window).height() - $('#container').outerHeight())/2
  });
});

// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();
</script>
```

This works great except if I scroll to the bottom of the page it will not center the DIV in the middle of the browser screen based on the new coordinates of where I am at in the position of the page. So my question is, if I click to open this DIV, what can I do to center the DIV if I am scrolled to the bottom of a long page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script will only centre on the window at the top of the page.. top is relative to the document, not the window - try position:fixed and then your centring script should work.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this: [jsFiddle Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/Baac2/)

I added and animate function to move the `#container` when the window is scrolled:

```
var $scrollingDiv = $("#container");
 $(window).scroll(function(){  
     $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, 500, 'easeInOutSine' );            
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure exactly your question, but i do something similar like this

```
var top= $(document).scrollTop()+($(window).height()/2) - ($('#container').outerWidth()/2);
var left=(window.innerWidth/2) - ($('#container').outerWidth()/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way for a horizontal center is to give `margin: 0 auto` CSS. As for the vertical centering, you current way is good enough.